# Prove that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a transcendental element over a field $E$, and $F=E(\alpha)$. Prove that for any subfield $K$ of $F$ containing $E$ as a proper subset, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$.

Can anyone give me some hint? I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is a subset of $E(\alpha)$ properly containing $E$, it must contain as an element some nonconstant rational function of $\alpha$.  To get a feel for what's going on, suppose for instance that $\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha} \in K$.